# Application freezes when phone font size (or anything affecting UI) changes while app is running

Tags: c#, maui-blazor

Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.0 Preview 4.0) 
Default .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Application, net8.0 (Preview)
sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-win-x64

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create default .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App with net8.0,
2. Run the App on Android Emulator ex. Pixel5 - Api33,
3. Change phone orientation portrait/landscape. Everything works fine,
4. Minimize application,
5. Open android Settings->Display->Display text and size. Change font size to bigger or smaller,

   - it does not have to be font size. You may set font to bold or change the screen size etc. ,
6. Bring the application to front,
7. Change the orientation or try to tap any button,
8. App freezes. Black rectangle on the screen instead of the app.

Problem exists in both release/debug mode.

Same thing happens on real devices like s8+ (Android 9), A70(Android 11), s20(Android 13). 
Problem **does not exist** in Default .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App, net7.0 (Long term support).
We can run two apps, built with net7.0 and net8.0, simultaneously on the same emulator/device and change the font size. The one built with net7.0 works fine. Other freezes. 
Has anyone had the same problem and knows how to solve it ?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue totally on .NET8. It's weird that OnResume method would not be  invoked when switching back to the app. You may raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).